# No speed limit on German highways - why?

Tags: law, germany, transportation

I wonder what are the historical circumstances that led to lack of speed limit on German federal *Autobahn* network. There is an advisory 130 km/h limit, but it is not mandatory one nor obeyed practically. (As a side note, Wikipedia says, there used to be a mandatory 100 km/h limit in former GDR and it was not retained after re-unification.)

Please provide the reasons (plus sources) that would differentiate Germany from
other "comparable" countries (for example, France) that did introduce the limit on some historical occasion.

Comment: Can't find any sources for this, so treat it as an anecdote: When I asked more or less the same (in Berlin, while renting a 911 for the sole purpose of going crazy in the Autobahn) the answer was very simple, the "no speed limit" was to keep voters and the local industry happy. Germany has a long tradition in car manufacturing, and in certain areas almost everyone is tied to the auto industry and letting people drive their cars to the max is _very_ good for sales.

Comment: Well, why won't anybody ask "why there **is limit outside** Germany?" Why do we all agree that limits are good?

Comment: The 100 km/h limit in the former GDR is really not comparable, because except for the three connections between Germany and Berlin, they didn't really have Autobahns that lived up to any reasonable standard. I remember one stretch of "Autobahn" between Goerlitz and Dresden where there was a single on-ramp for both directions; you had to cross eastbound traffic to get to the westbound lane. The other reason for the 100 km/h speed limit on the Germany/Berline routes was that the fines were a source of "currency" revenue for East Germany.

Comment: I really wouldn't want to go faster than 100km/h with a Trabi :) Even at a lower speed than that, the security in case of accident should have been terrible.

Comment: @Voitcus we don't really agree limits are good. But with many "safety" regulations, everyone fears to remove them, since if anything (even unrelated!!) happens, they will be held accountable. So we are full of silly, ineffective, rules.

Comment: @Lohoris so if a car would crash into one of your children at 180km/h wouldn't you blame the driver for going to fast ? Yes, without speed limits it *is* possible that people will be responsible and drive at an appropriate speed not to put others into danger, but I *know* there will be many who won't, especially in the cathegory of 18-20 yo boys.

Comment: @Bregalad 10km/h is enough to kill people, if you are dumb or drunk enough. Going faster than your skill allows is always dangerous.

Comment: @Lohoris Yes, and it's mostly a matter of braking distance. Doubling the speed quadruples braking distance, but drivers don't "feel" it, which is why there is speed limits. Removing speed limits completely could be possible but then passing a driving licence should be much harder, and people should be required to re-pass their licence regularly, and with a specific vehicle. Also it would be more complicated to proof they drove too fast in regard to visibility/brake distance/weather condition than just comparing with a fixed arbitrary speed.

Comment: This question has received multiple answers. If they haven't answered your question, it would be helpful to explain why. Otherwise, please [consider marking one accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/261831). If you have further follow-up questions, you should ask them in a separate post.

Comment: @Bregalad We have that system (**veeery inofficially**) where I live. I'm simplifying it a bit but in practice, a cop won't stop you if you break the rules as long as i appears safe. And the opposite applies too. How do we prove that you were going too fast in case of an accident (like hitting an elk)? Well, you **did** hit an elk, so your speed **wasn't** correctly controlled. Done! No accident = good driving. Something happens = bad driving. Note, it's unofficial and based on my experience only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before the war, only a limit of 30 km/h inside towns was in force, but no other general speed limits.

In the Third Reich, there was a general speed limit of 40km/h inside of towns, and 80km/h outside. This was mostly to conserve resources for the war (and because several high ranking Nazis had been killed in accidents on the new *Autobahnen*).
Being a war-time law, it was nullified in 1952 by the Bundestag - without replacement. At that time, most European countries didn't have speed limits.

Up to 1957, no speed limits were in force in (West) Germany at all. In 1957, a speed limit of 50 km/h inside towns was introduced.
Only in 1972, a speed limit of 100 km/h on roads outside of cities (except on the *Autobahn* and on *Autostraßen* with at least 2 lanes per direction of traffic) was introduced.

A good overview of the 50 km/h limit can be found [here](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/technik-motor/auto-verkehr/tempolimit-50-jahre-tempo-50-1460250.html) (in German).

A general speed limit was often discussed (see the second article quoted by *Hauser*), but never introduced. In a recent poll, 89 percent were against a general speed limit on *Autobahnen*. Politicians don't want o oppose this.

Also, German car manufacturers say that most of the inventions they made (especially for security), were made because they were needed to safely travel at high speeds. On a more practical level, they fear for their position in the market, as they make the kind of cars that are best for the *Autobahn*. They have the money (to contribute to parties and candidates) and one of the killer arguments ("every seventh job in Germany directly or indirectly is dependent on making cars"), and they use both.

A long (and somewhat unstructured) article on that topic can be found in [Der SPIEGEL](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-53364550.html).

Comment: Accepting after a long wait. In truth, only the second paragraph is relevant. It doesn't explicitly say that **the reason is that German population lived under the draconian 80 limit early when other countries didn't**, but it seems like a crucial point that differentiates Germany; exactly what I was looking for. Although I'd gladly change the "accepted" status if anybody dug deeper around here, as of now this answer is by far the best one.

Answer (score 27):

Let me answer as a German with an analogy.

You can compare the German speed limit to weapon ownership in US. Any party suggesting introduction of a general speed limit would conduct political suicide and face serious debates with the automobile lobby and voters (most workplaces here come from this branch). Most rational arguments points towards a speed limit (less traffic jam/noise, environmental pollution...), but similar to US weapon industry, there are to many automobile fanatics in *all* political parties (either green, liberal, democrats, conservative). You can only lose voters with this topic.

The historical circumstances are simply that a lot of automobile inventions were made in Germany, the car is a status symbol for many here.

[These articles](http://www.study-in.de/en/--12035/) sheds some light on the special situation in Germany:

> When the introduction of a national speed limit for Germany's
>   Autobahns (motorways and highways) was discussed in the 1980s,
>   automobile associations of all kinds demanded the "Freedom of the
>   roads for free citizens" – with at least some success back then. And
>   even today, Germany still does not have a general speed limit.
>   Although a maximum speed of 130 km/h is recommended, where no road
>   sign expressly indicates this speed limit, drivers can decide for
>   themselves how fast they would like to travel. If you should pick up a
>   few angry comments about "Points in Flensburg" during a conversation,
>   you can be sure that those involved are talking about the
>   Kraftfahrt-Bundesamt (Federal Motor Transport Authority). Some 7.1
>   million car drivers are currently listed there. All of them ignored
>   the signs and were caught driving too fast. The quicker they were
>   travelling, the higher the fine and the number of points they
>   collected. Travelling in your own car
>
> Germany is seen as a country of car enthusiasts. No wonder then that
>   this is where the first motor vehicle was invented. Today, the
>   automotive industry is one of the country's largest employers. There
>   is practically no other item that Germans would spend as much money on
>   as a car. For students, having their own car is generally a luxury.
>   The prices for petrol and diesel are higher than in other European
>   countries and the required third-party insurance
>   (Haftpflichtversicherung) also costs a lot of money. And still, many
>   afford themselves the luxury of a car of their own.

[Further](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/why-germany-put-the-brakes-on-398202.html):

> The German "Economic Miracle" of the Fifties and Sixties were boom
>   times for the car and road building industry. It was not until the
>   world oil crisis of the early Seventies that the country's politicians
>   were forced to contemplate the idea of speed restrictions on
>   Autobhans. The then West German government reacted by imposing a ban
>   on Sunday driving and introducing a 100kph speed limit for the
>   duration of the crisis.
>
> During the 111 days that the speed limit was in force, **Germany's
>   equivalent of Britain's Automobile Association, the 16-million member
>   ADAC**, got wind of government plans to make the restriction
>   permanent. The immensely powerful organisation responded by promoting
>   a slogan which has now become part of everyday German vocabulary:
>   "Freie Fahrt Für Frei Bürger", which translates prosaically into
>   (Limit) **Free Driving for Free Citizens**.
>
> The massive public opposition to Autobahn speed limits that ensued
>   had, until yesterday, stopped the idea from ever being taken up again
>   by either of Germany's two main parties. Safety has hardly been an
>   issue either, in fact the **government has mounted campaigns stressing
>   how statistically safe the Autobahn is in comparison to two-lane
>   highways**.
>
> The German car lobby, headed by the influential giants, Mercedes,
>   Volkswagen, Porsche and BMW, has for decades persuaded the political
>   establishment to reject the idea of blanket motorway speed limits.
>   **To ensure the co-operation of the main parties, Daimler, BMW and Porsche donated a total of 2m (£1.4m) to them in the run up to
>   Germany's 2005 general election**.

Comment: [Porsche’s Home State May Face Speed Limits After Greens Victory](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2011-03-28/porsche-s-home-state-may-face-speed-limits-after-greens-victory.html) (just saying...)

Comment: This answer is as good when I substitute "French" for "German".

Comment: @kubanczyk I cannot really name empirical or rational arguments,as this is a matter of culture, similar to weapon ownership in US. It just did grow this way (there was ever a strong automobile industry in Germany, machine engineering is one of the most important industrial sectors here). A french car doesn't have the status character of a german Mercedes, BMW, Audi, Porsche all over the world. Formula One is a very popular sport here too. I cannot explain why the french like it so much to eat and bake baguette bread, this is simply culture grown over decades and because they invented good food

Comment: @YannisRizos This is the first local district president from a green party ever here in Germany, of course speed limit is no timeless law here, the status character of cars here vanishes too, smartphone is more important than own car for many kids here nowadays. Nonentheless I strongly doubt a nationwide speed limit will be introduced in Germany in the next 2 decades. The green party won in this district because of Fukushima and a environmental political agenda know plays a more important role for the voters here, but this can also be just a temporal effect until Fukushima is forgotten...

Comment: I have absolutely no idea about German politics, I just found that article while I was researching my answer here (since abandoned) and I thought it would be interesting to share.

Comment: How much would it cost the society to actually implement the speed limit: setup monitors, process violations etc.? Just because the idea of no limit has industrial lobbysts doesn't mean that it's wrong.

Comment: @Jake J True. And think about aircraft. Are there no emission problems there? So maybe a common speed limit for both? Like 400 km/h, I wonder what would passengers and industrial lobby say to that?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason may simply be that there doesn't **need** to be a speed limit, and that there never was a compelling reason to implement one. For the most part, freeway speeds are self-regulating.

Secondly, it is simply not true that there is no speed limit on the freeway. There is no **general** speed limit, but most stretches of the Autobahn do have individual speed limits. Only a few long-distance stretches between cities truly don't have a speed limit.

Those stretches are usually two lanes in each direction, and frequently heavily congested (during summer vacation traveling season, traffic jams of 100km are not unheard of). In winter, snow and ice also naturally limits speeds.

Basically, there are very few stretches and times when you really can drive very fast, often only in the middle of the night.

Keep in mind that in the USA, for a long time, there was no speed limit on the freeways, either. If it hadn't been for the 1970s oil crisis, there still would be no speed limit.

Disclaimer: things may have changed. It has been a quarter century since I lived in Germany.

Comment: Re "In the USA, for a long time, there was no speed limit on the freeways." - Not accurate. Before 1973, the *national* government did not enforce a maximum speed; the limit was left up to each *state*. There were *some* places that had no speed limit; AFAIK, those tended to be sparsely populated. And even in those places, you might not be allowed to go any speed you wanted, there were state rules such as "*reasonable and proper*"; e.g. you could be cited for driving at an unsafe speed, relative to conditions. Almost nowhere could you exceed 100 mph, without a state trooper stopping you.

Comment: It is also a matter of responsible behaviour. If you have bad road conditions, weather, traffic, you drive slower than any given speed limit. If you are not capable of making such a judgement : don't drive.